# webscraping: replacing tags manually

Tags: r, rvest

I am dealing and playing around with "rvest". Getting the data with "read_html" is ok.

```
library(rvest)
# suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
library(stringr)
library(XML)

# get house data
houseurl <- "http://boekhoff.de/immobilien/gepflegtes-zweifamilienhaus-in-ellwuerden/"
house <- read_html(houseurl)
house
```

I have some problems processing the data.  My problems are commented in the source.

```
## eleminating <br>-tags in address
# using the following commands causes error using "html_nodes"
str_extract_all(house,"<br>") ## show all linebreaks
# replacing <br> in whitespace " ", 
house <- str_replace_all(house,"<br>", " ")
```

now reading out details but it seems, that doesn't work

```
houseattribut <- house %>%
html_nodes(css = "div.col-2 li p.data-left")   %>% 
html_text(trim=TRUE) 
# shows "Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : ... "
# but all attributes are shown on screen
houseattribut
```

Without replacing the "br"-tags manually its working, but the "html_text" tightened the strings together

```
housedetails <- house %>%
html_nodes(css = "div.col-2 li p.data-right") %>% 
html_text()
housedetails
# the same error shows "Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : ... "
# but all details are shown on screen

housedetails[4]
# in the source there is: "Ellwürder Straße 17<br>26954 Nordenham"
# at <br>-tag should be a whitespace
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `read_html`, `house` is a `xml_document`, after you use `str_replace_all` it became a `chr`, so, when you try to filter nodes again, its not more a `xml_document`and it gives you the error.

You need to convert it again to `xml_document` or apply the replace node by node.

Something like that:

```
house <- read_html(str_replace_all(house,"<br>", " "))
```

Full code:

```
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(stringr)

houseurl <- "http://boekhoff.de/immobilien/gepflegtes-zweifamilienhaus-in-ellwuerden/"
house <- read_html(houseurl)

house <- read_html(str_replace_all(house,"<br>", " "))

housedetails <- house %>%
    html_nodes(css = "div.col-2 li p.data-right") %>% 
    html_text()

housedetails[4]
#> [1] "EllwÃ¼rder StraÃŸeÂ 17 26954Â Nordenham"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I'm looking for.